# How can I make a command in Ubuntu usable only with sudo?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, blacklist

I need to make a command in Ubuntu (in this case gsettings, but whatever) runnable only with sudo permissions (so essentially I need to run the command with 'sudo gsettings' and I need to type the password). Any help?

Comment: Have you tried to change the owner of the file to root and change it’s rights to 700 (or whatever for group and other without execute rights)?

Comment: `gsettings` is *not* supposed to be run with sudo. It modifies your user's configuration, which should be owned by your user, or you might see start seeing other things randomly fail.